# Inserting records into multiple tables using results from first insert

Tags: postgresql

I'm pretty raw when it comes to PostgreSQL and have some experience with SQL Server. This question is about practice, because I've read many things.

I want to insert a record (user) and then take that `userID` and insert a couple more records into a couple more tables.

Traditionally, I would use something like a stored procedure or trigger to handle that. I've seen that functions exist in postgreSQL (no stored procedure?), but I also saw that those are not transactional.

I'm hoping I can find a solution that's transactional, either with a trigger or stored procedure.

Foreign keys are currently not added (will exist at some point, just not at this point in development):

Example (pass in $name, $password, $address, $group_id, $interestsJson):

```
insert into user (name, pwd, address) 
values ($name, $password, $address)

insert into user_group (user_id, group_id) 
values (NEW_USER_ID_ABOVE, $group_id)

insert into user_interests (user_id, interests) 
value (NEW_USER_ID_ABOVE, $interestsJson)
```

Comment: On the foreign keys - We're at the stage of testing our models, so I haven't added them yet. But will not go adding data without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions **are** transactional - they participate in the transaction of the caller. You can put all three inserts into a single function and call that. The caller has to commit the transaction however.

```
create or replace function do_inserts(p_name text, p_password text, p_address text, p_group_id integer, p_interest jsonb)
as
$$
declare 
  l_user_id integer;
begin 
   insert into "user" (name, pwd, address) 
   values (p_name, p_password, p_address)
   returning id into l_user_id;

   insert into "group" (user_id, group_id) 
   values (l_user_id, p_group_id);

   insert into user_interests (user_id, interests)
   values (l_user_id, p_interests);
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then you can do:

```
begin;
select do_inserts(...);
commit;
```

---

Alternatively you can do everything in a single statement:

```
with new_user as (
   insert into "user" (name, pwd, address) 
   values (..., ..., ....)
   returning
), new_group as (
   insert into "group" (user_id, group_id) 
   values ((select id from new_user), ...);
)
insert into user_interests (user_id, interests)
values ((select id from new_user), ...);
```

---

With Postgres 11 (to be released in Q4/2018) you will be able to use stored procedures where you can use `commit`